# EnterAlwaysCollapsed does not bring back the Toolbar when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm using `layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"` with a toolbar `minHeight` of `0dip`, with the intention of only bringing back the `Toolbar` when my first visible item in the `RecyclerView` is visible (as opposed to `enterAlways`, which brings it back immediately whenever the `RecyclerView` is scrolled up). However, the toolbar is never showing again after I scroll it off the screen. What am I missing?

Comment: Show please your layout file

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) app?

Comment: @karaokyo I was able to find the solution by playing around the cheesesquare app, thank you. If you add a half-decent answer that links to that app, I'll accept and give you the bounty.

Comment: @josephus your question was quite vague, which is why it is hard to answer and why I didn't want to answer it. I also already got the bounty on your other question, which was along the same vein. For future questions, it might be good to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then, you might not even have to offer a bounty to get your answer! That said, I would of course enjoy having a +150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the design support library sample app: [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

The proper way to implement your described behavior is to just use the scroll flag by itself:

```
layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without seeing your code, as a guess this could be one of two things:

---

1.

It seems there is a bug with this, the view disappears from the screen when set with a min-height greater than zero.Then returns min height when scroll down begins, and full height when the scroll reaches the top.

I think that your min-height of zero may be interfering with your return. As if the scrollview vanishes with a non zero min height, who knows what is going on to cause that, the zero min height may make it impossible to return with this bug.

Have a look at this [video](http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/designlibrary/scrolling102.mp4) found here  http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en half way down the page.

I quote from this page:

> enterAlwaysCollapsed - This flag defines how View enter back into the
>   screen. When your view has declared a minHeight and you use this flag,
>   your View will only enter at its minimum height (i.e., ‘collapsed’),
>   only re-expanding to its full height when the scrolling view has
>   reached it’s top. Use it with scroll flag like this:
>   scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed
>
> **Anyway it seems like it doesn't work as described in minHeight part.**

*I added emphasis.*

---

2.

You have not formatted your code correctly.

From [Android's Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) I quote on "CoordinatorLayout and the app bar":

> One note: all views using the scroll flag must be declared before
>   views that do not use the flag. This ensures that all views exit from
>   the top, leaving the fixed elements behind.

This link also goes into more detail about how to use `enterAlwaysCollapsed` and is worth looking at.

Let me know if this solves your problem.